# BPMN 2.0 Repeat Activity on a Fixed Date

Tags: bpmn

I have a question related on example:

We have an activity X which has to be executed every 10th day of the month and produce a report as output. How do I build a BPMN model to reflect this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer here really depends on what BPM tool you are using and the defined capabilities of that tool. Generally, you would create a process with a timed start event such that the process only initiates every 10th day of the month. Then, activity X would execute, it builds a report, and finally outputs that report as the process output.

If a start event that can recognize the 10th day of the month is not available, I would create that same process, but instead give it a message start event. Then, I would create a separate process that runs daily. In this process, I would simply check if the current date is the 10th day of the month. If so, fire a message to kick off that first process. If not, end.